# Search and replace with the result of a command

Tags: vim

In vim, I want to search and replace a text. But I want to replace it with the output of a command.

Given the text:

```
{ "_template": "foo" }
{ "_template": "foo" }
```

I want to search and replace that to become:

```
{ "_id": "239c55fd-538e-485f-8588-83d9735b6819" }
{ "_id": "2ae9f49f-244c-47b0-8f0f-c6c46e860af3" }
```

The latter is the result of the unix/linux command `uuidgen`.

It would look something like `s:/"_template": "foo"/"_id": "<uuidgen>"/`, but I'm unsure what to do at `<uuidgen>`. The command uuidgen is just an example, but it would be a command that takes no arguments and does not need any stdin passed in (like for example `wc` or so would).

It needs to call the command for each search/replace again.

Is this possible at all with vim? Or should I better use sed and/or awk instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hum...

Something like that?

```
:s/"_template": "foo"/\='"_id": "'.trim(system('uuidgen')).'"'
```

The key is `:s-\=`

Comment: I was not aware of [sub-replace-expression](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression). Thanks for pointing me there!